# Rails: deep nested resources gives error: undefined method 'comments'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, comments, nested-forms

I'm getting this error `undefined method 'comments'` in my rails application. I know I shouldn't do a >level 1 nested resources, but I don't know how to apply the correct way in this case.

Currently this is my routes:

```
resources :performance_indicators  do
    resources :improvement_actions do
      member do
        put "like" => "improvement_actions#upvote"
        put "unlike" => "improvement_actions#downvote"
      end
      resources :comments
    end
  end
```

As I said I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in PerformanceIndicators#show
Showing .../app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't know if my problem is in the controller. Anyone can help? :)

**EDIT:**

My comment/_form:

```
    <%= form_for([@performance_indicator, @improvement_action, @improvement_action.comments.build]) do |f| %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my CommentsController:

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_improvement_action


  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /comments/new
    def new
      @comment = @improvement_action.comments.new
    end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create

    @comment = @improvement_action.comments.new(comment_params)

      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@improvement_action.performance_indicator, @improvement_action], notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: [@improvement_action, @comment] }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

  def set_improvement_action
    @improvement_action = ImprovementAction.includes(:comments).find(params[:improvement_action_id])
  end
end
```

Here Is my PerformanceIndicatorController:

```
class PerformanceIndicatorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_performance_indicator, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  # GET /performance_indicators
  # GET /performance_indicators.json
  def index
    @performance_indicators = PerformanceIndicator.all
  end

  # GET /performance_indicators/1
  # GET /performance_indicators/1.json
  def show
    #@performance_indicators = PerformanceIndicator.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # GET /performance_indicators/new
  def new
    @performance_indicator = PerformanceIndicator.new
    @comments = Comment.new
  end

  # GET /performance_indicators/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /performance_indicators
  # POST /performance_indicators.json
  def create
    @performance_indicator = PerformanceIndicator.new(performance_indicator_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @performance_indicator.save
        format.html { redirect_to @performance_indicator, notice: 'Performance indicator was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @performance_indicator }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @performance_indicator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /performance_indicators/1
  # PATCH/PUT /performance_indicators/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @performance_indicator.update(performance_indicator_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @performance_indicator, notice: 'Performance indicator was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @performance_indicator }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @performance_indicator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /performance_indicators/1
  # DELETE /performance_indicators/1.json
  def destroy
    @performance_indicator.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to performance_indicators_url, notice: 'Performance indicator was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def set_comment
    @improvement_action = ImprovementAction.find(params[:improvement_action_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_performance_indicator
      @performance_indicator = PerformanceIndicator.find(params[:id])
    end



    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def performance_indicator_params
      params.require(:performance_indicator).permit(:name, :numberTimesIdentifiedProblems, :numberTimesAnalysed)
    end



end
```

Comment: It's being called in your comments form. Post that. The code you posted isn't relevant to your error. You're calling `something.comments` and that `something` is `nil`

Comment: i edited, with the comments form

Comment: In which view page you are rendering that partial file?

Comment: it is in _improvement_actions (which is also a partial called on performance indicator) like this : <%= render 'comments/form' %> . The structure is this: performance indicators -> improvement_actions -> comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start by fixing the deep nesting.

```
resources :performance_indicators, shallow: true do
  resources :improvement_actions
end

resources :improvement_actions, only: [] do
  member do
    put "like" => "improvement_actions#upvote"
    put "unlike" => "improvement_actions#downvote"
  end

  resources :comments
end
```

`only: []` is a clever trick that nests routes under a resource but suppresses the generation of routes. We want that since the first block actually declares all the routes we need.

```
                                       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
    performance_indicator_improvement_actions GET    /performance_indicators/:performance_indicator_id/improvement_actions(.:format)          improvement_actions#index
                                              POST   /performance_indicators/:performance_indicator_id/improvement_actions(.:format)          improvement_actions#create
 new_performance_indicator_improvement_action GET    /performance_indicators/:performance_indicator_id/improvement_actions/new(.:format)      improvement_actions#new
edit_performance_indicator_improvement_action GET    /performance_indicators/:performance_indicator_id/improvement_actions/:id/edit(.:format) improvement_actions#edit
     performance_indicator_improvement_action GET    /performance_indicators/:performance_indicator_id/improvement_actions/:id(.:format)      improvement_actions#show
                                              PATCH  /performance_indicators/:performance_indicator_id/improvement_actions/:id(.:format)      improvement_actions#update
                                              PUT    /performance_indicators/:performance_indicator_id/improvement_actions/:id(.:format)      improvement_actions#update
                                              DELETE /performance_indicators/:performance_indicator_id/improvement_actions/:id(.:format)      improvement_actions#destroy
                       performance_indicators GET    /performance_indicators(.:format)                                                        performance_indicators#index
                                              POST   /performance_indicators(.:format)                                                        performance_indicators#create
                    new_performance_indicator GET    /performance_indicators/new(.:format)                                                    performance_indicators#new
                   edit_performance_indicator GET    /performance_indicators/:id/edit(.:format)                                               performance_indicators#edit
                        performance_indicator GET    /performance_indicators/:id(.:format)                                                    performance_indicators#show
                                              PATCH  /performance_indicators/:id(.:format)                                                    performance_indicators#update
                                              PUT    /performance_indicators/:id(.:format)                                                    performance_indicators#update
                                              DELETE /performance_indicators/:id(.:format)                                                    performance_indicators#destroy
                      like_improvement_action PUT    /improvement_actions/:id/like(.:format)                                                  improvement_actions#upvote
                    unlike_improvement_action PUT    /improvement_actions/:id/unlike(.:format)                                                improvement_actions#downvote
                  improvement_action_comments GET    /improvement_actions/:improvement_action_id/comments(.:format)                           comments#index
                                              POST   /improvement_actions/:improvement_action_id/comments(.:format)                           comments#create
               new_improvement_action_comment GET    /improvement_actions/:improvement_action_id/comments/new(.:format)                       comments#new
              edit_improvement_action_comment GET    /improvement_actions/:improvement_action_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)                  comments#edit
                   improvement_action_comment GET    /improvement_actions/:improvement_action_id/comments/:id(.:format)                       comments#show
                                              PATCH  /improvement_actions/:improvement_action_id/comments/:id(.:format)                       comments#update
                                              PUT    /improvement_actions/:improvement_action_id/comments/:id(.:format)                       comments#update
                                              DELETE /improvement_actions/:improvement_action_id/comments/:id(.:format)                       comments#destroy
```

Un-nesting the resources means there will be a lot less hoops to jump through.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_improvement_action

  # GET /improvement_actions/:improvement_action_id/comments/new
  def new
    @comment = @improvement_action.comments.new 
  end

  # POST /improvement_actions/:improvement_action_id/comments
  def create
    @comment = @improvement_action.comments.new(comment_params) do |c|
      # @todo - you should associate comment with the user who created it at some point.
      # c.author = current_user
    end

    # note that you where saving the record twice!
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to [@improvement_action.performance_indicator, @improvement_action], notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: [@improvement_action, @comment] }        
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end

  # ...

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end

    def set_improvement_action
      @improvement_action = ImprovementAction.includes(:comments)
                              .find(params[:improvement_action_id])
    end

end
```

You should handle seeding with new records on the controller side if possible.

```
<%= form_for([@improvement_action, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks for the help :) that way gives me this error: 

ArgumentError in PerformanceIndicators#show
Showing C:/.../app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Comment: If you want to use it in your show action you need to set `@comment = @improvement_action.comments.new` in the controller or change the form to `[@improvement_action, @comment  || @improvement_action.comments.new]`

Comment: it gives me again the first error: undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Dude, you need to learn how to do some basic problem solving or you will never get anywhere. `undefined method ... for nil:NilClass` means you are not setting a variable correctly. Check the controller.